# how to center image gallery on my wordpress website

Tags: css, wordpress, image, centering, image-gallery

I have a gallery on my website (koolcycles.com) under the main picture and I would like to have it centered in the page (ie have the blue dotted line axis move to where the red line axis is in the attached image)

I was told I need to change the width in the CSS file.

I would like to know what I need to change and where!

[image: home page screenshot]

Comment: it would help if you allow right click. Edit: never mind it was the images I couldn't right click.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
.content {
    width: 67%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You can't centre an element with `float` applied. Remove `float` and add a `margin: 0 auto;` and it will be centered. For future reference, you can align elements or text either by using `margin: 0 auto 0 auto` (top, right, bottom, left) or `text-align: center;`. Bare in mind though, to align an element using margins, you need to specify a width either in pixels or percentages.

[image]